# Unexpected sinusoidal wave at low voltage setting on oscilloscope?

Tags: voltage, time, probe, waveform

I'm fairly new to electronics in general, and I'm learning to use an oscilloscope.

I have a 10X probe attached to a 1uF capacitor that is completely discharged. When I set the time interval on the o-scope for that channel at 10ms, and the voltage interval at 50mV I can quite clearly see a very low amplitude sinusoidal wave.

In fact, completely removing the capacitor and making a connection between the probe and ground produces the same sinusoidal wave.

Is this just a tiny bit of output voltage on the probe, or something external?

Comment: Estimate the frequency of this sine wave.  I would guess that what you see is 60Hz picked up from mains AC.

Comment: Looks to be exactly 200Hz actually.

Comment: Off hand, I don't know of a common household source of 200Hz.  If you want to hunt down the source, turn off your appliances one by one and observe the signal.

Comment: I didn't think about that. So, it's just some poorly isolated current running through some wire in one of my appliances...not my o-scope.

Comment: Provide proper earthing to your scope.  The wave form is noise from power frequency.

Comment: Just bought the scope used. Realize the grounding pin has been broken off. Didn't even think about that.

Comment: Do you see the same *frequency* (probably at a different amplitude) when you touch the probe tip alone, without touching the ground clip?

Comment: OK, to use the scope you absolutely need 2 connections - the probe tip to what you're measuring, and the ground-clip, usually to the thing called 'ground' on the circuit you're measuring (but not always).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small waves like this on a scope are almost always from noise from another device. Make sure that the outlets are grounded properly. 200Hz is a strange frequency for noise to be appearing on, but it is too exact to not be a device of some kind. You should also check the lights in your room as well as other appliances.

50mV peak to peak is relatively small. If it isn't interfering with your other measurements it shouldn't be a problem.

You can also try shielding your power supplies, probe, or scope, or any other appliances with tin foil to reduce or eliminate noise.